# How to determine the quartiles and deciles from a given data set

Tags: python, data-science

I am writing a program to perform 2 steps.

## Step 1. calculate Q1, Q2, Q3

## Step 2. calculate D1, D2, D3, D4, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9

The program that I have written is constructed like so:

```
# Author: Evan Gertis
# Date 10/08
# program: quartiles & deciles

wages       = [250.00,259.99,260.00,269.99,270.00,279.99,280.00,289.99,290.00,299.99,300.00,309.99,310.00,319.99]
n_employees = [8,10,16,14,10,5,2]
total       = 65

def quartile(n,w,employees):
    return wages[2*n-1] + total/n - n_employees[2*n-1]/n_employees[2*n]*10

# Step 1. calculate Q1, Q2, Q3
print(quartile(2,wages,n_employees))

# Step 2. calculate D1, D2, D3, D4, D4, D5, D6, D7, D8, D9
```

The data set is:

[image]

As part of this question I am seeking an understanding of the decile calculation shown below:

[image]

I'd like to use numpy to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unambiguously compute statistics using a range as input.

Using the lower bin end (you could use the max or average of you prefer) and [`numpy.quantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html):

```
np.quantile(np.repeat(wages[::2], n_employees), q=[0.25, .5, .75])
```

Output: `array([260., 270., 290.])`

Using the average of the bins:

```
wages = np.array(wages)

np.quantile(np.repeat((wages[::2]+wages[::2])/2, n_employees), q=[0.25, .5, .75])
```

Output: `array([260., 270., 290.])`

For the deciles, do the same with `q=np.arange(.1, 1, .1)`

Comment: Thank you. However, the actual quantile values are 268.25, 279.06, and 290.75. The deciles do not come out as expected either.